# TypeScript Classes - Declaring an Array of Objects as a Property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop

I'm looking for the most appropriate way to declare an array of objects as a property when declaring a class using TypeScript. This is for use with a form that will have an unknown number of checkboxes for an Angular Template-Driven form.

Is it advisable to have a separate class for the objects, as I have below, or is there a better way? Tried searching for advice on this in many ways and can't find much. Am I way off the mark here?

```
export class Companion {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    chosen: boolean;
}

export class ExampleForm {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    companions: Companion[];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I do it. Also, depending on your backend (if you have one) this may deserialize esaier depending what Object structure you are expecting on your form post.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, interested why it might deserialize more easily?

Comment: Why `class` and not just `interface`?

Comment: @jcalz Because I need to use it to create objects for the checkboxes?

Comment: There is an [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-guide) issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19632) which has a good discussion on the pros/cons of classes and interfaces for models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that most people in Typescript (not just Angular) don't use classes for these models. We use interfaces for them. So your `ExampleForm` would look like this.

```
export class ExampleForm{
    // This was what you already had
    companions: Companion[];
}
```

and then use an interface to define `Companion`.

```
export interface Companion{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    chosen: boolean;
}
```

Doing it like this will allow you to just use plain JavaScript objects for the `Companion`s. But you will get type safety on each of those objects. It's pretty awesome.

Comment: Got it, thanks, that makes sense. Knew something smelled wrong but couldn't figure it out. I'd tried `companions: { id: string, name: string, chosen: boolean }[];` but TypeScript didn't like it when assigning objects. This makes much more sense, will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, just tried it and it is indeed awesome :) Thanks again.

Comment: A related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76420420/typescript-how-to-express-an-array-of-objects-as-a-typescript-interface